# C++: what does this constructor format mean?

Tags: c++, c++11

I,m reading a c++ code , and  i can't understand a section of it . here is the code :

```
    BatteryBase.h

 00001 
00002 #ifndef __Battery_Base_H__
00003 #define __Battery_Base_H__
00004 
00005 #include "CommonIncludes.h"
00006 #include "cConsumer.h"
00007 #define SUCCESS 1
00008 #define FAIL 0
00009 #define BATTERY_OUT 2
00010 
00012 
00017 class BatteryBase : public cSimpleModule
00018 {
00019         protected:
00020                 double      m_Energy;
00021                 double      m_CurrentEnergy;
00022                 int         m_State;
00023                 cModule     *pCoOrdinator; 
00024                 cArray      ConsumerList;
00025                 simtime_t lastTimeOut; 
00026                 cMessage *batteryOut;
00027                 cConsumer *consumer;
00028 
00029         public:
00030                 Module_Class_Members(BatteryBase, cSimpleModule, 0); //constructo
00031                 
00032 
00034 
00036                 virtual double GetTotalEnergy(void) const;
.
.
.
00088                 virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) = 0;
00089 
00091 
00094                 virtual int RegisterCoordinator(void);
00095 };
00096 
00097 #endif // __Battery_Base_H__
```

I can't understand what does it mean in line 32. why the BatteryBase class constructor uses the BatteryBase class as parameter ?
whould you help me please?

Comment: Where is `Module_Class_Members`defined?  Is it a macro?

Answer (score 3):

```
Module_Class_Members(BatteryBase, cSimpleModule, 0); //constructor
```

This is not the constructor of your `class`. The constructor of your `class` would be something like :

```
BatteryBase() {}
```

[`Module_Class_Members`](http://www.omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/group__MacrosReg.html#g96dc1cfbc4574094cdd29d04c1a4d94a) is a MACRO that was helping the developer to create a default constructor for his class. In your case, it creates a constructor who should look like :

```
BaseClass() : cSimpleModule() {}
```

But as it is said in the documentation that this macro is **deprecated**, you should replace it by :

```
public:
    BaseClass() : cSimpleModule() {}
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly the default constructor which the compiler would automatically define for you? I'd just completely remove the line.

Answer (score 0):

It is a macro that calls constructor and sets up inheritance relationships. `Module_Class_Members(BatteryBase, cSimpleModule, 0)`. It means that the class `BatteryBase` has been derived from `cSimpleModule` that is an abstract class which provides basic functionality for any module. Will give you another example. For e.g.

```
class MyDerivedModule : public MyModule
{

Module_Class_Members (MyDerivedModule,MyModule, 0);    
// and again user-specific methods
// follow
};`
```

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: The macro appears in a class definition. That means that this macro might merely *define* a c-tor. Without knowing *what* this macro defines, any answer is useless.

Comment: This is the official documentation : http://www.omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/group__MacrosReg.html#g96dc1cfbc4574094cdd29d04c1a4d94a.
Kindly "find out what this macro does" and give an answer if you find it.

Comment: The description of this macro given in your link would be the actual answer ;)

Comment: I explained what the macro does in simple understandable language. The documentation doesn't actually provide the macro working. Thanks for your comment. :)